# Vue Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a method to toggle a value of the user's profile. The method triggers whenever the form is changed (whenever the checkbox is clicked).

The form looks like this:

```
<form v-if="!this.StateUser.message.isPrivate" @change="privateTrue(this.StateUser.message._id)">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
</form>
```

And my method looks like this:

```
privateTrue (id) {
      axios.patch('/user/private-true/' + id)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
    },
```

The error it returns is
**Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'StateUser')"**

StateUser is a getter from Vuex, and it seems like it can not read that value. Is this a problem with Vuex, or the v-on method not accepting vuex values? The issue is the same if I replace with the $store variable.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Try to remove the `this` and use `StateUser` directly

Comment: Seem likes `StateUser` is null there so you can't use `StateUser.message`. How do you map `StateUser` to the vue component?

Comment: As long as you have retrieved the getter from Vuex to a computed for example, https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access, it should be mapped to the component

Comment: StateUser is simply an object of the logged in user. Removing 'this' solved my issue